# Why can the font family of the svg image change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fonts

Font family of svg file is `font-family="HelveticaNeue-Bold, Helvetica Neue"`. I input the svg file in my website. Then I check in my chrome browser and the result is true, the font -family is `Helvetica`

But my friend try to access my website, the font family of the image is change. The font family is times new roman

How could this happen? how do I set it so that the font family doesn't change when accessed anywhere

Comment: Probably your friends devices doesn't have font installed, if this is the case put the font file in your server or put a stylesheet from sources like google fonts

Comment: @blacksheep although not installed. it should work

Comment: @SuccessMan why do you think it should work? if there's no font file on the device how does the rendering engine know how to draw it?

Comment: @blacksheep What do you mean devices doesn't have font installed? I had put the font file in my server and call google fonts. But it does not work

Comment: @RobertLongson I have font file in my project and I had call it by css. But it's the same

Comment: Here is a nice Q&A about adding custom or hosted fonts in svg https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/how-do-i-use-a-custom-font-in-an-svg-image-on-my-site

Answer (score 3):

The font has to be available to the visitor, via the browser.
Basically you need to put the right font files on the server and include them via CSS.

If you dont, your pc will get the closest font to render the text of the default setting. In your case this is Helvetica. Your friend doesnt have this installed, so he gets the default Times.

[How to add fonts to your site](https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website)

Or:
[This will do the heavy lifting for you](https://vecta.io/nano)

Depending on how you made the SVG, you could also convert the type to shapes, then you wont need a font, but lose the ability to easily edit the text.

Comment: I had put the font files on my server and include via css. But it does not work